# LDAP Object class error while creating user

Tags: linux, ldap

when i am installing LDAP after installation i need to create users with some attribute
i am passing this but giving me a error of object class

dn: uid=Mihir,ou=people,dc=domain,dc=com
objectClass: inetOrgPerson
objectClass: posixAccount
objectClass: shadowAccount
cn: Mihir
sn: mj
userPassword: {SSHA}ti90VYQst24GhEyduqSaa0go0td/9hGO
loginShell: /bin/bash
uidNumber: 1000
gidNumber: 1000
homeDirectory: /home/username

when i am running give me this error:-
adding new entry "uid=Mihir,ou=people,dc=nodomain"
ldap_add: Object class violation (65)
        additional info: object class 'inetOrgPerson' requires attribute 'sn'

Answer (score 1):

I think, LDAP "ab ovo" can not support multiple inheritance.
If you export your items in an ldif file, you can see, the listed objectClasses are part of the same inheritance chain. e.g.

```
objectclass: person
objectclass: organizationalPerson
objectclass: inetOrgPerson
objectclass: top
```

shadowAccout looks like that

```
( 1.3.6.1.1.1.2.1
 NAME 'shadowAccount'
 DESC 'Standard LDAP objectclass'
 SUP top
 AUXILIARY
 MUST uid
 MAY ( userPassword $
  shadowLastChange $
  shadowMin $
  shadowMax $
  shadowWarning $
  shadowInactive $
  shadowExpire $
  shadowFlag $
  description )
 X-ORIGIN 'RFC 2307' )
```

AUXILIARY could work.

Have you tested with a simple inetOrgPerson without auxiliary objectclasses (as a first step)?


Have you tried add user from ldif per ldapadd? (first delete if exists)

**ldif content:**

```
version: 1

dn: uid=Mihir,ou=people,dc=domain,dc=com
objectClass: shadowAccount
objectClass: posixAccount
objectClass: top
objectClass: person
objectClass: organizationalPerson
objectClass: inetOrgPerson
cn: Mihir
gidNumber: 1000
homeDirectory: /home/username
sn: mi
uid: Mihir
uidNumber: 1000
userPassword: plain text...(!)
```

Comment: I could not reproduce Object class violation (65)